# Prove $\operatorname{res}_{z=z_0} f(z) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \exists F(z)$ such that $F'(z) = f(z) \;(\forall z \in B(z_0,r)\setminus\{z_0\}) $

Tags: complex-analysis

> If $f$ has an isolated singularity at $z_0$ prove:
> $$\operatorname{res}_{z=z_0} f(z) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \exists F(z) \text{ such that } F'(z) = f(z) \quad(\forall z \in B(z_0,R)\setminus\{z_0\}) $$

Could someone give me some points on how to prove this?

#### Proof:

I think I know how to prove $\Leftarrow$:

If $\exists F(z) \text{ such that } F'(z) = f(z) \;(\forall z \in B(z_0,R)\setminus\{z_0\}) = \Omega$ than according to Morera's theorem:

$$\int_\Gamma f(z)\operatorname dz = 0 \qquad \text{ for each closed } \Gamma \in \Omega$$

In the special case of $\partial B(z_0,r)$ with $0<r<R$ then

$$\operatorname*{res}_{z=z_0} f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int\limits_{\partial B(z_0,r)} f(z) \operatorname d z = 0$$

#### However:

- The prerequisites for Morera are $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ without holes continous over $\Omega$ then $\ldots$

  Isn't this a problem since $\Omega$ does not contain $z_0$?
- How do I prove $\Rightarrow$?

Answer (score 1):

Just express $f$ using [Laurent series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series). Then both statements are equivalent to the expansion having vanishing $z^{-1}$ term (the uniform convergence in the annulus makes it possible to interchange integration and summation, for the first statement, and derivatives and summation, for the second statement).